# T-SQL problems with optional prompts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having problems trying to get the below MPAN and TimePeriodStart to be mandatory parameters and the rest to be optional. However when I run the prompts no results come through. Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

```
alter procedure task2assigned 
(
@MPAN varchar(13),
@TimePeriodStart datetime = null,
@TimePeriodEnd datetime = null,
@BSCValidation varchar(1) = null,
@ReadType varchar(1) = null
)

A

SELECT * FROM TABLES
```

Here is the whole query, as the problem lies with the parameters:

```
where a.J0003 = (@MPAN)
and d.J0016 >= DateAdd(mm,-36,@TimePeriodStart)
and (@TimePeriodEnd is null or d.J0016 <= DateAdd(mm,-36,@TimePeriodEnd))
and (@BSCValidation = null or d.J0022 = @BSCValidation)
and (d.J0171 is null or d.J0171 = @ReadType)
```

Comment: Since we have no idea how your data look like, we cannot possibly answer this question. Pls provide us with sample data, expected output, and the actual output from the query.

Comment: Thank you shadow, no idea i did that. That fixed it cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why you suddenly put  **@BSCValidation = null** .. `null` can not be compared using `=` sign .... anyway below script might help you

**Edit 1**: As you asked in comment ..

```
alter procedure task2assigned
(
@MPAN varchar(13),
@TimePeriodStart datetime = DATEADD(year,3,GETDATE()),
@TimePeriodEnd datetime = GETDATE(),
@BSCValidation varchar(1) = null,
@ReadType varchar(1) = null
)

AS
BEGIN

   SELECT * FROM TABLES
   WHERE a.J0003 = @MPAN
   AND (@TimePeriodStart IS NULL OR d.J0016 >= DateAdd(mm,-36,@TimePeriodStart))
   AND (@TimePeriodEnd IS NULL OR d.J0016 <= DateAdd(mm,-36,@TimePeriodEnd))
   AND (@BSCValidation IS NULL OR d.J0022 = @BSCValidation)
   AND (@ReadType IS NULL  OR ISNULL(d.J0171,@ReadType) = @ReadType)

END
```

Comment: Also if you could please help, i have been asked "Uses start and end date as parameters (if they are not provided please set default to 3 years previous from the day the query is run)", how would i do that as default on the parameter. Thanks